# iOS - How to prevent animation from flickering at Keyboard dismissal?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, facebook-pop

I'm having an issue with an animation being affected by the Keyboard dismissal, the animation is running infinitely moving a background image a few pixels around the screen, the screen contains also a UITextField, every time the keyboard is hidden the animation flickers. Anybody has experienced this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody encounters the same issue:

My problem was related to Autolayout. I was trying to animate the center of the view instead of the layout constraints, so propably when the keyboard was shown/hidden the layout method on the view was called causing the mentioned flickering.